# In Ubuntu 12.04, /dev/.udev/db no longer exists

Tags: 12.04, udev

Prior to Ubuntu 12.04 the udev database was available and updated at /dev/.udev/db but in 12.04 and greater, the directory /dev/.udev/ exists but the database doesn't. Does anyone know where it went?

Answer (score 3):

After running an `strace` on the `udevadm info` command, I saw that it now looks in `/run/udev/data`. However, instead of the devices being listed by kernel name (e.g. `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb`), they are listed by their major and minor number and device type.

So I ran `strace -f -e open udevadm info -q all -n /dev/sda` and I saw:

```
open("/run/udev/data/b8:0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

It opens `b8:0` because `/dev/sda` is a block special file with a major number of 8 and a minor number of 0. You will also see other data files like `c10:1` and `input:input1`. I don't know what the input is for, but I know that the `c` is for character special files and the `10:1` is for a major number of 10 and a minor number of 1.

I found the information about block special files and character special files by looking at `man mknod`.

As a note: I am running Ubuntu 13.04 and udevadm version 175.